# Flow for iOS application that saves images and has a PHP backend: how to increase speed?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, image, swift

I have an iOS application, and it saves images to user profiles. I have a page where a user can see other users. I have an endpoint on a PHP backend that allows me to fetch the image for a given user ID. I am able to:

1) Take a picture on the phone

2) Save that picture to that user in the database (using a base64 encoded string representation of the PNG of the image)

3) Re-download that image as a string in base64

4) Display the image on another page to another user

The problem is, though, that these blobs on the backend are big (about `2.5MB` each), and it takes about 20-30 seconds per image to load or upload. Is there a better way of doing this, that would increase my performance?

Comment: Is it really part of you use case that these images are so big? A typical image with 1000x1000 pixels for display on iOS should not be bigger thatn ~500KB (in my experience). Also you should make sure that your connection uses gzip, this will reduce about 25% of data since you use base64 encoding. Can you please provide data what actually takes up the time in your case so we can focus on that?

Comment: Huh, I knew the sizing seemed off, but I didn't realize it was at that scale. I'm just converting the image picked from the `UIImagePickerController` and converting that to base64 string encoding through the PNG transformer (`UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`) built into iOS. I do no shrinking of the image, so maybe that's something I should do client side?

Comment: Do you need PNG? JPEG will be much smaller and is still very good for most applications (especially for user icons)

Comment: You should try using NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5); to compress your image to JPEG, that will reduce the size drastically without hurting your quality (as long as you don't intend to print the images)

Comment: Wow, that reduced the size of the BLOB to `200KB`, which seems completely fine, I could even compress more. Thanks Nils!

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer, so you can 'finish' this question. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick summary of what we spoke about in the comments:

1. Use gzip for transfer (expected 25% increase of speed due to base64 encoding)
2. Store images as JPEG, by performing

`NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);`
The magic constant `0.5` is a number I found to still give good image quality but still heavy compression

3. Optionally reduce resolution of the image

Answer (score 0):

You should store the image as a file and save a reference to it in the database. To shrink file size you should resize the image on the client side to your needs. For better user experience you could first download a lower resolution image (when you're showing the picture) and load the full resolution image afterwards, but you're overall download size will increase.

Comment: How would I do this through a PHP endpoint? I'm basically passing around JSON, so not sure how I'd save a file